# Calculate sum of a Dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "X" : [1, 3, 10, 16, 26, 36],
    "Y" : [42, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to print sum of X. `sum_of_X = df[0].sum()` won't work.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please show your code as text, not an image. And what is the exact error message?

Comment: You're trying to index a dictionary like a list which fails for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {
    "X" : [1, 3, 10, 16, 26, 36],
    "Y" : [42, 50, 75, 100, 150, 200]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df["X"].sum())
```

Which gives me `92`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python way and just `sum(df['X'])` or even `sum(data['X'])` (You don't really need to crate the dataframe at all for that)

Or you can use pandas' built-in and use `df['X'].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a dataframe?

```
sum(data['X'])
```